Something like @JsonTypeInfo/@JsonSubTypes for @ConfigurationProperties?
tl;dr; Is there a way to have @ConfigurationProperties read into specialized subclasses?
I am defining a structure in application properties to capture a variety of WebClient configurations. This is what the structure may look like:
application:
    webclients:
        service1:
            base-url: https://service1/api
            auth-type: basic-auth
            username: user1
            password: password1
        service2:
            base-url: https://service2/api
            auth-type: oauth2
            client-registration: service2-client-reg

The example shows two types of web clients, one for Service1 configured with Basic Auth, and a second one for Service2, referencing a spring.security.oauth2.client.registration entry. There would likely be more in the future.
The default approach to defining a @ConfigurationProperties class for this structure would look like this:
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
public class WebClientConfigurations {
  private Map<String, WebClientConfig> webclients;
}

@Data
public class WebClientConfig {
  private String baseUrl;
  private String authType; // could be an enum in real code
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String clientRegistration;
}

Depending on the auth-type, either username + password must be populated, or client-registration. Populating both would be ambiguous (and there should probably be validation via @InitializingBean). There is an ongoing argument at work about using such a "multi-purpose" class to capture such either-or variations, as opposed to mandatory + optional fields. Whether it is acceptable practice (since we are dealing with application properties and what Spring Boot provides) or whether it is a violation of object modeling that you can't have a "DogCat".
If this was pure Java, I would obviously create two derived classes, BasicAuthWebClientConfig and OAuth2WebClientConfig, that contain the specialized fields. In fact, when working with the Jackson library, it is possible to use the @JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations to have the deserialization process choose and populate appropriate subclasses, depending on the JSON input data.
I searched long and far and was not able to find any comparable mechanism for reading application properties into specialized subclasses. Did I miss anything? Any other thoughts or advice?

In the meantime I have changed the structure of the webclients section to this:
application:
    webclients:
        basic-auth:
            service1:
                base-url: https://service1/api
                username: user1
                password: password1
        oauth2:
            service2:
                base-url: https://service2/api
                client-registration: service2-client-reg

and a matching config properties class:
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.webclients")
public class WebClientConfigurations {
  private Map<String, BasicAuthWebClientConfig> basicAuth = new HashMap<>();
  private Map<String, OAuth2WebClientConfig> oauth2 = new HashMap<>();
}

It is a bit more verbose due to the extra level, but it allows to load application properties into two specific subclasses that both derive from a WebClientConfigBase class.

There is a bit more to this undertaking than what I described in the original question, and from what it looks like this approach actually works very well for it.
The WebClientConfigurations class exists in a library that is shared across over a dozen microservices. Some of those microservices will need to use more "advanced" web client configurations, like specifying additional headers that get sent with every request, or overriding default HTTP settings. In such cases, a microservice may introduce a new subtype of WebClientConfigBase and then extend the WebClientConfigurations class like this:
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.webclients")
public class CustomWebClientConfigurations extends WebClientConfigurations {
  private Map<String, CustomAuthWebClientConfig> custom = new HashMap<>();
}

Now the following structure could be used:
application:
    webclients:
        basic-auth:
            ...
        oauth2:
            ...
        custom:
            ...

This enhancement with an additional, custom web client config wouldn't have been possible with the initial approach I described in my question, due to the strongly-typed Map<String, WebClientConfig> field.
